# Switching between two Ethernet magnetics and one simple Phy

Tags: ethernet, phy

I'm deep into a project and I would like to ask how can I switch 2 ethernet interfaces to single PHY. I know that there're some suitable analog switches for this purpose like [MAX4890](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4890-MAX4892.pdf), but I don't fully understand how does this IC work.

It's supposed that Ethernet signals are differential, depending on which interface you use, these levels could be +/-1V and +/-2,5V. 
My question is, how does this IC work with single and positive supply if needs to switch differential signals? In the same way, the PHY has also single supply.

Comment: What is the bigger problem here? If it's just "make the ethernet port available in two places" have you considered using an ethernet switch chip instead of a phy?

Answer (score 4):

Since OP has not mentioned the PHY being used, taking Micrel [KSZ8021RNL/8031RNL](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/Ethernet/datasheets/ksz8021rnl_8031rnl.pdf) as an example.Please look at the electrical specifications of the PHY

[image: KSZ]. You can see the differential output measured after 1:1 transfer lies between min. 0.95V to max. 1.05V, which is not the -ive voltage. For more details of the PHY electrical specification you can look page #33 onwards of KSZ821RNL datasheet.

With this I just wanted to highlight that differential signal need not always swing between positive to negative voltage. It can swing between more **positive(say 3.0V)** to **less positive( say 1.0V)**, this will also be considered as differential signal.

For the basics of differential signalling you can look into [app note](http://file:///C:/Users/anand.rai/Desktop/D'top/Tech%20Docs/2002OCT11_POW_AN01.pdf) from Lattice semiconductor, which also talks about advantages of differential signalling.
There can be many more levels for LVDS as shown below:[image: LVDS]. The image source is Analog Devices application note [AN-1177](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-1177.pdf). And this also talks about multipoint LVDS.

Now coming to MAXIM [MAX4890/MAX4891/MAX4892](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4890-MAX4892.pdf) LAN switch, you can easily use this switching between two ethernet RJ45 to a single PHY, as it shown as an example circuit page #39 of the switch datasheet, image for reference below:[image: switch]

As a suggestion just make sure both your PHY and this LAN switch operate on the same voltage. And make sure to have a closer look at their logic levels as well.