# Connect and disconnect Ethernet line

Tags: ethernet, rj45, analog-switch

I need an IC to connect and disconnect the network cable line (TX+ and TX- lines to connect/disconnect)

Can I use an analog switch IC?

[image]

Comment: Related, or possible duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641151/ethernet-multiplexing-using-hcf4066 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159002/switching-between-two-ethernet-magnetics-and-one-simple-phy

Comment: As @TimWilliams commented before, this is already discussed in a previous question. I would suggest the same as it is suggested on that post, use a relay, keep it simple. The signal and the voltage supply lines you were going to use to control that "analog switch ic" can be used to control the relay, you will need to add one transistor and one resistor but is expensive and does not occupy much space.

Comment: If you're doing this to prtoect a device from malevalent traffic, and you can't cut all four lines, I recommend disconnected the receiving lines of the protected device (not the tx)..  That way your device doesn't even gat the ARP request or any broadcasts.  +1 for relay: very simple, easy to do, works well.  (Unless you have some borderline ethernet lengths and maximum speed requirements.)

Comment: Make sure the paths have exactly the same length and keep the untwisted part of the circuit as short as possible.